# Pandas fillna: Output still has NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a strange problem in Pandas. I have a Dataframe with several `NaN` values. I thought I could fill those `NaN` values using column means (that is, fill every `NaN` value with its column mean) but when I try the following

```
  col_means = mydf.apply(np.mean, 0)
  mydf = mydf.fillna(value=col_means)
```

I still see some `NaN` values. Why?

Is it because I have more `NaN` values in my original dataframe than entries in `col_means`? And what exactly is the difference between fill-by-column vs fill-by-row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with the `df.mean()` Series (which is dict-like):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan], [np.nan, 4], [5, 6]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
    0   1
0   1 NaN
1 NaN   4
2   5   6

In [13]: df.fillna(df.mean())
Out[13]:
   0  1
0  1  5
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

Note: that [`df.mean()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) is the row-wise mean, which gives the fill values:

```
In [14]: df.mean()
Out[14]:
0    3
1    5
dtype: float64
```

Note: if `df.mean()` has some NaN values then these will be used in the DataFrame's fillna, perhaps you want to use a [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on this Series i.e.

```
df.mean().fillna(0)
df.fillna(df.mean().fillna(0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I get `nan` is not defined with your first line.

Comment: You need to do `from numpy import nan`

Comment: Thanks. I also just realized that my `col_means` also had `nan` values in them!

Comment: @AndyHayden His example should work though. `df.apply(mean, 0)` and `df.mean()` should be equal. At least for pandas `v0.12.0-145-g5a2daa4`

Comment: @PhillipCloud My problem apparently was that some colums only had `NaN` values, so  `df.mean()` had some `NaN` entries itself! I also acknowledge that I didn't know how to use the `dict` in `fillna` properly

Comment: Ah ok. Carry on then. :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud ah good point. I guess the answer is having NaNs in the dict fills them with NaNs :)

Comment: By the way, what is the difference between `fill-by-column` and `fill-by-row` when using `value=X` (also part of the OP) ?

Comment: @user815423426 one takes the mean row-wise, the other column-wise (i.e. average over the column, vs average over the row)

Comment: Thanks but a that point `df.fillna(value=X, axis=Y)` we have that  `value` is a dictionary, so what is the role of `axis` in this case?

Comment: That could be wart. Not sure if the axis argument has any effect in `fillna`.

Comment: @PhillipCloud it's a NotImplementedError?

Comment: @PhillipCloud can just transpose do transpose it

Comment: @AndyHayden Sure. You could do it that way. Still a wart though :) I think it should either be taken out or implemented. `fillna` along the rows seems like it would be more trouble than it's worth.